# Spring Boot 2 MockMVC unit testing with RequestPart and MultipartFile

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, multipart, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I have the below email controller for sending email with RequestPart DTO object (userDTO) and Multipart file (3 files upload max). where userDTO is a JSON object

I tried using postman and it works perfectly for sending email with attachments, however i need to develop unit testing using MockMVC and I am not able to find any suitable examples on these combinations of Multipart and Request Part. When i tried using the below test class, i'm not able to hit  my controller which will trigger email.

**My Controller**

```
   @PostMapping(path = "/api/email/sendEmail)
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> sendEmail(@RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile[] uploadfile,
            @RequestPart UserDto userDTO, WebRequest webRequest) {

            webRequest.setAttribute("userDTO", userDTO, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
            UserDto obj = emailService.sendEmail(userDTO, uploadfile);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(obj, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

**My JSON (userDTO) which comes in request part**

```
{
"sender":"sender@gmail.com",
"recipients":"receiver@gmail.com",
"subject":"Hi Testing Mail API",
"content":"This is my email"
}
```

**My Test Class**

```
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ServicesApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;


      @Test
        public void testEmail() throws Exception {
            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();            
             mockMvc.perform(post("/api/email/sendEmail")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
               .content("{ \"sender\":\"sender@gmail.com\",\"recipients\":\"receiver@gmail.com\",\"subject\":\"Hi Testing Mail API\",\"content\":\"This is my email\"}")
               .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));


        }
```

Any leads would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I don't see why this question shouldn't be covered by the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests), to test your controller mock your dependencies like the `emailService` and perform a get request using MockMvc. Testing the email service is another question, maybe not spring related and possibly an integration test, but you didn't provide enough information regarding this service.

Comment: @sn42 Updated with my post with the snippet on the mockmvc.

Comment: The example in the linked documentation can be adapted quite easily to test your controller. To test your email service, integration tests with green mail could be an option.